# How to edit and save 8 bit indexed color logo?

Tags: css, image, png, photoshop, 8-bit

I bought RE/MAX fransichzing and I need edit official logo from remax.com in adobe photoshop.

But there is little problem with editing their logo in photoshop. If I open their png logo, layer is really wierd - image is in 8 bit indexed color: 
[image]

Logo must be transparent like on remax dot com.

Can you help me how can I edit this?

Comment: you can find a `vector logo` from this website.. hope this way it help you. http://www.logowik.com/remax-vector-logo-132907702653.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can change the image mode and bit depth in the `Image > Mode` menu in Photoshop.
So if you wanted to change it to RGB you'd click on `Image > Mode > RGB Colour`.

Also if you have permission to use and don't need to enlarge it you could just snatch the image from their homepage's sprite.

Comment: Yes, I know this. I snatched the image from their website. But if I open logo in photoshop and turn to RGB Color mode, then save the image as png...output file is not same as their original :/

Comment: Hmm. I tried it there; downloaded their sprite, cropped and saved and it was fine. Did you take any further steps before saving? Which method did you use to save the file?